Relaxing structure under different pressure and constant temperature with VASP
I am relaxaing the structure under 800 $^{\circ}$C and different pressure. I only want to set the pressure/force along the $z$ axis; rather than $x$ and $y$ axes.
I know that VASP cannot set pressure along single axis; therefore, I adapt the NVT ensemble and change the volume of the structure through adjusting the lattice constant along the $z$ axis; then, fit the relation between volume and the pressure.
Here is my INCAR file.
System = Structure
ISTART = 0
LWAVE = .FALSE.
LCHARG = .FALSE.
ISYM = 0
ICHARG = 2
IVDW = 12
ENCUT = 520
IBRION = 0
NSW = 20000
MDALGO = 2
TEBEG = 1075
TEEND = 1075
PSTRESS = 0.0
NBLOCK = 1
KBLOCK = 1
POTIM = 1.0
ISMEAR = 1
SIGMA = 0.01
ALGO = VeryFast
SMASS = 1.0
LREAL = Auto
PREC = Normal
ISIF = 2
NELMIN = 5
NELM = 60
NELMDL = -10
EDIFF = 1e-4
EDIFFG = -0.001
NPAR = 4

Is this method appropriate for such calculation? or Should I use the NPT ensemble to relax the structure and set external_pressure tag to apply the force along the $z$ axis?
Here is part of my OUTCAR file.
FORCE on cell =-STRESS in cart. coord.  units (eV):
  Direction    XX          YY          ZZ          XY          YZ          ZX
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Alpha Z  8668.66625  8668.66625  8668.66625
  Ewald    3845.45262  3649.23439************   -46.17309     0.39847    18.32697
  Hartree 72754.03067 72730.66570-39900.72954    -1.79151    -0.04281     9.38258
  E(xc)   -9528.75780 -9529.60680 -9537.40046    -0.21649    -0.00528    -0.00941
  Local  ************************128082.69597    41.53323    -0.82113   -27.06350
  n-local -3098.68980 -3099.29918 -3202.84313    -0.63631     0.13256    -0.04368
  augment 13675.16939 13677.53533 13566.94773    -1.20623    -0.14455     0.41592
  Kinetic 13978.45743 14028.61122 14135.08149    10.24112     0.51051     0.18325
  Fock        0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
  vdW       -86.32464   -86.03823   -86.39055     0.05523     0.01703     0.00330
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Total    -129.46492  -110.21603   -88.26556     1.80595     0.04481     1.19544
  in kB    -109.19917   -92.96340   -74.44894     1.52325     0.03779     1.00832
  external pressure =      -92.20 kB  Pullay stress =        0.00 kB

  kinetic pressure (ideal gas correction) =     10.79 kB
  total pressure  =    -81.42 kB
  Total+kin.   -97.452     -83.574     -63.223       1.925      -0.150       1.575

I only found a total pressure value. Is it possible to obtain the pressure along the $z$ axis?
Would anyone please give me some suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Sorry for not being useful, but I'm kinda more interested in how you would make sense of this. I mean, when you compress along the z axis, the x and y directions would bulge out, so there ought to be pressure along those directions too. What physical scenario are you actually looking for, such that you want to decouple the pressures?

@naturallyconsistent Thank you for the reply. Of course, there are pressures along all three directions but the pressure value should be different along different directions. I am just particularly interested in the pressure along the z axis. Would you please give me some more comments or can I use the NPT ensemble to relax the structure and set external_pressure tag to apply the force along the z axis? Thank you agian.

Sorry, I don't really know much about this kind of simulations, so I could not give better comments.
